# Mongdb Failed to start up (windows, version: 4.2.8)

Tags: mongodb

I have successfully downloaded mongdb community edition by following the instruction on the website. But when I try to start up mongdb by doing this:

> From Windows Explorer/File Explorer, go to C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\ directory and double-click on mongo.exe.

The computer tries to connect with a window that looks like cmd popping up, but that window will be gone after about 1 second.

And I have attempted the other method which I put this code:"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongo.exe" into cmd and try to start it up.
But it looks like it my computer is denying the operation :

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.8
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-07-21T16:26:34.816+0800 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-07-21T16:26:34.821+0800 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-07-21T16:26:34.821+0800 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

I would be really appreciated if someone can solve this problem for me.

Comment: Did you start the MongoDB service? (see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/index.html#run-mongodb-community-edition-as-a-windows-service)

Comment: I tried to install it again, but it says "service 'MongDB server(MongoDB)' (MongoDB) failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services."

Comment: Does the dbPath folder exist? It is quite common that one did not create it.